# CPU speed running at 0.46GHz instead of maximum speed 2.2 GHz

Tags: cpu-usage, cpu-speed

My Lenovo laptop with an Intel i5 processor runs almost all the time at a very low speed (0.46 GHz) instead of maximum speed (2.2 GHz). I read related posts here and changed the power management options to 100%, but still there is a drop in the speed. Also,  the fan gives a load noise during this drop and I suppose fan is running at high speed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It’s not in use. This is normal, although I’m not sure about your comment on fan speed. Expecting your CPU to run at maximum speed when not in use would be like revving your engine to 8000 RPMs to sit in your driveway. The system firmware isn’t going to allow that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your processor at full speed, You can use [Prime95 software](https://www.mersenne.org/download/#download) to make CPU Stress.

If you have low speed and fan is working at full speed check temperature at processor. You might need to replace thermal paste on the processor.

I hope that what You have in mind.

Comment: Thermal paste is not silicone... "[_They are typically heat-resistant_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone)"

Answer (score 0):

The drop in speed seems like SpeedStep (or a similar technology), where the CPU frequency drops in order to lower the operating temperature.

Like lluke said, try downloading software to check the CPU temperature; if it spikes during low CPU usage, you should get the fan/thermal paste checked out.